Does BimlExpress still support Visual Studio?
We heavily use BIML in our data projects for the development of SSIS packages, so BimlExpress is important to us.
So far, it looks like BimlExpress does not provide an installation for Visual Studio 2022 yet.
For Visual Studio 2019, it can install but will get an error saying "This extension was not loaded because it uses deprecated synchronous autoload APIs". See the screenshot below.
Our Question:
Is there a way we can still use Biml with Visual Studio, better to be one of the recent versions, e.g., 2022 or 2019.
Screenshot:

